# python urlpattern newbie question

Tags: django, url-pattern

I'm trying this pattern:

```
(r'^jobs/(?P<job_id>\d+)/$', job_handler)
```

To work with jobs/ and jobs/{job_id}, but the above expression doesn't cover the first case(jobs/), it only work if I do something like:

```
(r'^jobs/$', job_handler),
(r'^jobs/(?P<job_id>\d+)/$', job_handler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the second part optional:

```
(r'^jobs/(?:(?P<job_id>\d+)/)?$', job_handler)
```

Comment: And don't forget to make `job_id=None` in the definition of `job_handler`.